# What is the PHP equivalent to Python's Try: ... Except:

Tags: php, python, exception, try-catch

I am a strong Python programmer, but not quite there when it comes to PHP. I need to try something, and if that doesn't work out, do something else.

---

**This is what it would look like in Python:**

```
try:
      print "stuf"
except:
      print "something else"
```

What would this be in PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
try {

    // do stuff ...

} catch (Exception $e) {

    print($e->getMessage());

}
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: This was what I needed, thanks. I'll accept this answer when I can in about 8 or 9 mins.

Comment: @mizipzor, it worked great! @ts, sorry I hadn't accepted it yet, forgot to last night.

Answer (score 7):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

```
try {
    print 'stuff';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

Note: this only works for exceptions, not errors.

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php for that.

Answer (score 1):

PHP does not natively support error catching like Python does, unless you override the default behavior and [set your own error handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php). PHP's `try` - `catch` was only recently added to the language in version 5, and it can only catch exceptions you explicitly `throw`.

So basically, PHP distinguishes between errors and exceptions. Errors haven't been modularized and made available to the user like they have been in Python. I believe that's related to the fact that PHP began as a [collection of dynamic web scripts](http://us.php.net/manual/en/history.php.php), grew and gained more features over time, and only more recently offered improved OOP support (i.e., version 5); whereas Python fundamentally supports OOP and other meta-functionality. And exception handling [from the beginning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Python).

Here's an example usage (again, a `throw` is necessary, or else nothing will be caught):

```
function oops($a)
{
    if (!$a) {
        throw new Exception('empty variable');
    }
    return "oops, $a";
}

try {
    print oops($b);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print "Error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can handle PHP errors like they were exceptions by using [set_error_handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)

In this error handler function you can throw various exception, according to error level for instance.

By doing this you can treat any error (including programming errors) in a common way.

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5 has the [exception model](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php):

```
try {
    print 'stuff';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to catch exceptions, take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

You could try something like

```
try {
echo "Stuff";
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo "Something Else";
}
```